# Find rows where all group values are nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO
u_cols = ['word','count']
audit_trail = StringIO('''
test 1
testing 24
tested 
again 5
begin 
again 6
begin
again
''')

df = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep=" ", names = u_cols  )
```

I can groupby to find how many values are null:

```
df.groupby('word')['count'].apply(list)

word
again      [5.0, 6.0, nan]
begin           [nan, nan]
test                 [1.0]
tested               [nan]
testing             [24.0]
Name: count, dtype: object
```

**If the group count is greater than 1 and if all the values are nan then do not include such entries.**

```
Expected: 
again      [5.0, 6.0, nan]
test                 [1.0]
tested               [nan]
testing             [24.0]
```

In order to get these results, the word "*begin*" should be removed from the dataframe.

```
df[df.word != "begin"]
word    count
0   test    1.0
1   testing     24.0
2   tested  NaN
3   again   5.0
5   again   6.0
7   again   NaN
```

How do I find which words should be removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. With `groupby` and `filter`

```
df.groupby('word').filter(lambda x: not (x['count'].isna().all() and len(x) > 1))
```

#### 2. With `groupby` and  `transform`

```
g = df.groupby('word')['count']
m = g.transform('count').eq(0) & g.transform('size').gt(1)
df[~m]
```

#### 3. With `groupby` and `agg`

```
s = df.groupby('word')['count'].agg(['count', 'size'])
m = s['count'].eq(0) & s['size'].gt(1)
df[~df['word'].isin(m[m].index)]
```

---

```
      word  count
0     test    1.0
1  testing   24.0
2   tested    NaN
3    again    5.0
5    again    6.0
7    again    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first check if the values are duplicated based on name and count. This will identify all rows which appear more than 1. Then using groupby and transform (`all`) you can check if all the values are nan:

```
# checks for duplicated rows in word and count
c1 = df.duplicated(['word','count'],keep=False) 
# checks if all values in group is nan
c2 = df['count'].isna().groupby(df['word']).transform('all')
out = df[~(c1&c2)]
```

---

```
print(out)

      word  count
0     test    1.0
1  testing   24.0
2   tested    NaN
3    again    5.0
5    again    6.0
7    again    NaN
```